# Copy build history from one job to another job

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that is a declarative pipeline. It's URL is `$JENKINS_URL/job/dnscheck/`.

I started using Bitbucket projects on Jenkins, and now that `Jenkinsfile` is also discovered and the same job lives at `$JENKINS_URL/job/website/job/dnscheck/job/master/`

I want to copy the entire history (log files etc) from `$JENKINS_URL/job/dnscheck/` to `$JENKINS_URL/job/website/job/dnscheck/job/master/`, and then delete `$JENKINS_URL/job/dnscheck/`.

1. *Can* I do that?
2. If yes, *how* do I do that?
3. I don't want to overwrite existing files

Answer (score 2):

On the master, the logs are all stored in `${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/<path/to/job>/builds/`, unless overridden by a system property [jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties). They consist of a series of numbered directories with a `log` file (the build log) inside and possibly some additional data files (eg: build.xml, changelog.xml, injectedEnvVars.txt).

There are also some sym-links for last builds (good/bad, etc.), both inside the jobs directory and inside the builds directory. You *could* copy all the directories over (renumber if you have conflicts) AND update the sym-links accordingly. You may also need to reset the last build ( Number of builds since the start of the project ) to n+1 so that the next build number increments w/o overlapping. It's in a file inside /nextBuildNumber.

Finally, you must get Jenkins to recognize the new content since Jenkins caches everything. You can do that by either restarting the system, reloading the configuration from disk or less drastically, reload the data on the one job, something like:

```
def configXMLFile = job.getConfigFile();
def file = configXMLFile.getFile();
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
job.updateByXml(new StreamSource(is));
job.save();
```